# How to empty a 2d char array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am still new with C and I am trying to empty a 2d char array. Here is the declaration:

```
char arg_array = (char**)calloc(strlen(buf), sizeof (char**));
for(i = 0; i<(strlen(buf)); i++)
{
    arg_array[i] = (char*) calloc (strlen(buf), sizeof(char*));
}
```

Here is where I try to empty it:

```
void make_empty(char **arg_array)
{
     int i;
     for(i = 0; i <= BUFSIZ; i++)
     {
        arg_array[i][0] = '\0';
     }
     return;
}
```

Any help is appreciated

So, am I doing it right because this seems to give me segfaults when I try to add data to the array again and then print it?

Empty is just to have it empty - how can I explain more? lol

Comment: you are just modifying the first element of each sub-array... and what is "empty" in your context??

Comment: Have another variable like j, then create an inner for loop with it from 0 to columnSize - 1. Change BUFSIZE to rowSize - 1

Comment: You can empty a char * by making it's first character the null plug. (Even a noob such as myself knows that.) Here I am assuming that you can apply this to 2d arrays but when I "empty" it using this function and try to reuse it I get seg faults.

Comment: It is not true that you empty the char* by putting '\0' on the first position of string to which it points. It only makes functions like printf treat it like empty, zero-length string.
If it comes to your problem, char** is only a pointer to array-the program won't know what is the number of rows and columns of your array so you will have to pass them to your function separately.
Also, as somebody said before, you don't have to empty 2d array if you calloced it because calloc fills it with zeros.

Comment: wookie88 - can I apply this to a 2d array?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by applying ,,this'' to 2d array, but I've posted answer which will clear whole array as you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to empty it. Often in C, memory allocation is done with `malloc` which simply returns to you a block of memory which is deemed owned by the caller. When `calloc` is called, as well as returning you a block of memory, the memory is guaranteed to be initialized to 0. This means for all intents and purposes it is already 'empty'.

Also I'm not quite sure if your code does what you are intending. Let me explain what it does at the moment:

```
char arg_array = (char**)calloc(strlen(buf), sizeof (char**));
```

This line is simply wrong. In C, there is no need to cast pointers returned from `calloc` because they are of type `void *`, which is implicitly casted to any other pointer type. In this case, you are storing it in a `char` type which makes no sense. If you do this:

```
char ** arg_array = calloc(strlen(buf), sizeof (char**));
```

Then it allocates an array of pointers of `strlen(buf)` length. So if `buf` is `"hello"` then you have now allocated an array which can store 5 pointers.

```
for(i = 0; i<(strlen(buf)); i++)
{
  arg_array[i] = calloc (strlen(buf), sizeof(char*));
}
```

Again, I have removed the redundant cast. What this does is populates the array allocated earlier. Each index of the array now points to a `char` string of `strlen(buf) * sizeof(char *)` length. **This is probably not what you want.**

---

Your question is more clear to me now. It appears you want to remove the strings after populating them. You can do it two ways:

- Either `free` each of the pointers and allocate more space later as you did before
- Or set the first character of each of the strings to a null character

To free the pointers:

```
for(i = 0; i<(strlen(buf)); i++)
{
  free(arg_array[i]);
}
```

To set the first character of each string to a null character:

```
for(i = 0; i<(strlen(buf)); i++)
{
  arg_array[i][0] = '\0';
}
```

That is the same code as what you have originally and should be fine.

---

As proof, the following code will run without errors:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *  buf       = "hello";
    char ** arg_array = calloc(strlen(buf), sizeof (char**));
    unsigned int i;


    for(i = 0; i < strlen(buf); i++) {
        arg_array[i] = calloc(strlen(buf),
                sizeof(char *));
    }

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(buf); i++) {
        arg_array[i][0] = '\0';
    }

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(buf); i++) {
        free(arg_array[i]);
    }


    free(arg_array);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If your code is segfaulting, the problem is coming from somewhere else. Did you overwrite the `arg_array` variable? Are you sure `BUFSIZE` is equal to `strlen(buf)`?

Comment: I fill it up with words and I need to empty it again. I believe I stated this in the question. So this answer was perhaps not what I was looking for.

Comment: shouldn't you be using `sizeof(char *)` and `sizeof(char)` (which is 1 so unnecessary) for the loops instead of `sizeof(char **)` and `sizeof(char *)`?

Comment: @twain249: Yes, I did not correct this. `sizeof(char **)` is used where OP probably meant `sizeof(char *)`. However, both the values are equal. `sizeof(char)` is not used anywhere in my answer.

Comment: @MikeKwan I meant you have `arg_array[i] = calloc (strlen(buf), sizeof(char*));` that should either by `sizeof(char)` or simply `1`.

Comment: @twain249: Yep, I noted this is probably not what he intended in my answer already.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
void make_empty(char **arg_array, int rows, int cols)
    {
     int i,j;
     for(i = 0; i <rows; i++)
     {
       for(j=0; j<cols;j++)
       {
          arg_array[i][j] = '\0';
       }
     }
    return;
    }
```

Where rows is number of rows and cols number of cols of your array.

P.S. This function clears the whole array as you should always do. As I commented before, putting '\0' as a first char in string does not clear the whole row, it only makes the rest of it ,,invisible'' for functions like printf. Check this link for more information: http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Comment: `memset` would be a far easier alternative here.

Comment: I know, but I think with this example it will be easier for the author of question to understand what he misunderstood (see comments below question) ;).